# android show JS alerts in web view! (JS alerts not showing in lollipop devices due to the new webView engine)

Tags: javascript, android, webview, alert

I can't see JS alerts in the web view on my app. After i've used setWebChromeClient method it works on devices without the new web view engine. But i can't see my JS alerts on lollipop devices with the new web view engine.

Comment: Are you constructing your webview with your application or activity context? What do you get in logcat?

Comment: Hi @RobertoNovelo I'm getting "W/JsDialogHelper(6892): Cannot create a dialog, the WebView context is not an Activity" in my log cat.

Comment: Then create the webview with your application context. Assign a Activity class variable to your activity on your onresume, and then pass it to your webview constructor as context.

Comment: i tried this webView webviews = new WebView(getApplicationContext()); but still getting same message in my log cat.

Comment: At the top of your class declare a variable 
    public static Activity currentActivity= null;  and on your onResume 
        currentActivity=ActivityName.this; and then use it with webView webviews = new WebView(currentActivity); and see if that works please!

Comment: no luck after doing this. I'm getting the same log cat message.

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: GPSLocationHelper gps;
 public static Activity currentActivity = null;

 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.adultoffer_webview);
  final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
  currentActivity = AdultOfferWebView.this;
  WebView webviews = new WebView(currentActivity);

Comment: You are initializing your webview on your onCreate, which runs before onResume and i think currentActivity is not yet your Application.

Comment: I have moved my code to onResume() like you have suggested. Still not resolved. thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry man, this new web engine has caused some changes in my apps too. I'll ask later to see if anyone knows about it